# How do I plot clusters into a scatter graph in SAS?

Tags: sas

I created a dataset called clusteringds using the following code;

```
DATA clusterds;
INPUT ID$ title$ name$ age$ marital_status$ salary% postcode$ ethnic_origin$;
CARDS;
{Inserts Data Here}
run;
```

I then clustered the rows based on the ID, using the code below;

```
proc fastclus data = clusteringds maxc=5 maxiter=10 out=clus;
run;
```

This helped to create a data table called Clus, which is a combination of the table clusteringds and another variable called clusters, where each row is a cluster number from 1 to 5.

I would like to portray the clusters through a plot. I believe the code to do this comprises of;

```
proc &gplot data = clusteringds;
scatter;
run; 
quit;
```

But I am not to sure how to finish creating my plot. Can someone help please?

Comment: A Scatter plot will only show two dimensions at a time. Having many variables makes it hard especially when most are categorical.

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/06/26/color-clusters-in-dendogram.html

Answer (score 0):

A scatter plot can show two or three(bubble) or 4 (bubble+color) but then it becomes pretty busy.

Let's start simple here, with a single scatter plot

```
proc sgplot data=clus; *note you need to use the output data set here;
   scatter x= marital_status y=salary / group = cluster; *you may need to verify the cluster name;
   run; quit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If a scatter graph may mot be appropriate because i have many variables, isit possible to create a dendrogram to illustrate the different cluster groups? If so how would I alter the code you provided to create this please?

Comment: A dendrogram is significantly more complicated.